# toString method not displaying correctly

Tags: java, loops, printing, while-loop, tostring

i am just simply trying to print my tostring method to the screen but its not displaying the test with [] like this [SAIL, HIN100, Bindi, 10.0] i want to display it without the [] here is how im printing the toString method

```
        while (count < yachts.size()){
        System.out.println(yachts.toString());
        count++;
    }
```

here is my toString method

```
    public String toString (){
return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %1.1f, ",type, Boat_Code, BoatName, Length);
}
```

Comment: You're saying it's _not_ displaying with brackets, and that you _don't_ want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying the toString method of the Collection yachts, not the yacht itself, hence why the square bracket characters are displayed.

Try this instead:

```
int count = 0;
for(Yacht yacht : yachts)){
    System.out.print(yacht);
    count++;
    if(count < yachts.size()) {
        System.out.print(", "); 
    }
}
```

I've assumed you wish to output all elements on the same line with comma separated values (although these are already being used in your toString method). I've also assumed the toString method exists in a class called Yacht.

Edit: Using a while loop, you could use:

```
Iterator<Yacht> iter = yachts.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
    System.out.print(iter.next());
    if(iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(", "); 
    }
}
```